# Access functions in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

In my Component class (HeaderComponent),
I want to access the changeBtnColorBg function everytime I click the two functions changeBannerArrow() and changeBannerImg()

Those functions are triggered on the onclick event in the HTML side

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    imgTotal = 3;
    currentImg = 0;

    imgHdr = [];

    changeBannerImg(imgSelect){
        /* some code here */
        changeBtnColorBg(this.currentImg, imgSelect);
    }


    changeBannerArrow(imgSelect){
        from = this.currentImg;

        /* some code here*/
        to = this.currentImg;

        changeBtnColorBg(from, to);

    }

    changeBtnColorBg(from, to){
        this.imgHdr[from].selected = false; //change back to transparent

        this.imgHdr[to].selected = true; //change bg color
    }
}
```

But this structure produces an error of

> HeaderComponent.html:15 ERROR ReferenceError: changeBtnColorBg is not
>   defined

Can someone please help? I'm new to this

Comment: wow, Angular 7 requires no TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you missed the `this` in your `changeBannerArrow` and `changeBannerImg` methods

```
  changeBannerArrow(imgSelect){
        from = this.currentImg;

        /* some code here*/
        to = this.currentImg;

        this.changeBtnColorBg(from, to);
}


   changeBannerImg(imgSelect){
        /* some code here */
        this.changeBtnColorBg(this.currentImg, imgSelect);
    }
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for this! I figured it out a couple of seconds ago that the command line also displays an error (new to this) Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

```
changeBtnColorBg(this.currentImg, imgSelect);
```

to

```
this.changeBtnColorBg(this.currentImg, imgSelect); // add 'this'
```

Answer (score 0):

try and Make the following changes :

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
imgTotal = 3;
currentImg = 0;

imgHdr = [];

changeBannerImg(imgSelect){
    /* some code here */
    this.changeBtnColorBg(this.currentImg, imgSelect); // make change here
}


changeBannerArrow(imgSelect){
    from = this.currentImg;

    /* some code here*/
    to = this.currentImg;

    this.changeBtnColorBg(from, to); // make change here

}

changeBtnColorBg(from, to){
    this.imgHdr[from].selected = false; //change back to transparent

    this.imgHdr[to].selected = true; //change bg color
}
```

}